# How to display content for specific users

Tags: php

I want to display the billing organization that was added, just for specific users (determined by their ID). Is it possible?

```
<?php
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND account_id = '$account_id'";
$result3 = mysqli_query($link, $query3) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$billing_name_id = $_POST['billing_name_id'];
$billing_reference_num = $_POST['billing_reference_num'];
$transaction_amount = $_POST['transaction_amount'];
$account_number = $_POST['account_number'];
$account_id = $_POST['account_id'];
$query4 = "INSERT INTO billinghistory (billing_name_id, billing_reference_num, transaction_amount, account_id) 
       VALUES('$billing_name_id','$billing_reference_num', '$transaction_amount','$account_id')";
$result4 = mysqli_query($link, $query4) or die(mysqli_error($link));
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes - Most things are possible including finding the answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.. you have to get $user_id first then execute query for selected user.

```
<?php
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$account_id = $_POST['account_id'];
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND account_id = '$account_id'";
$result3 = mysqli_query($link, $query3) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);

$billing_name_id = $_POST['billing_name_id'];
$billing_reference_num = $_POST['billing_reference_num'];
$transaction_amount = $_POST['transaction_amount'];
$account_number = $_POST['account_number'];

$query4 = "INSERT INTO billinghistory (billing_name_id, billing_reference_num, transaction_amount, account_id) 
       VALUES('$billing_name_id','$billing_reference_num', '$transaction_amount','$account_id')";
$result4 = mysqli_query($link, $query4) or die(mysqli_error($link));
?>
```